# PostgreSQL VACUUM ANALYZE, invalid memory alloc request size

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, postgresql-13

When I'm executing `VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE) table_name;`

I get error

```
ERROR:  invalid memory alloc request size 2466264688
CONTEXT:  while vacuuming index "idx_name" of relation "public.table_name"
```

My `maintenance_work_mem` is 64mb, table contains about 50 million rows
This table has several indexes, other indexes are vacuumed fine
Any thoughts on what might be the cause of this error?

Comment: `maintenance_work_mem` is too small. Review Page 9: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/optimizing-monitoring-troubleshooting-vacuum-operations-postgresql.pdf

Comment: There's the phrase that vacuum operation creates batches of tuples by storing 8 bytes of information and 64 mb can accommodate eight million entries. So why it's too small?

Comment: @JohnHanley Increased `maintenance_work_mem` to 3gb - it didn't help